# Symfony2, doctrine2 & querybuilder: selecting the last entity of an association if available

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, associations, aggregation, dql

An entity "asset" is associated with "logEntries".
There could be 0..N log entries for each asset.

Part of each log entry is a field (or property) "status".
The current status of each asset, is defined in its most recent log entry.
If there are no log entries associated with an asset, its status is unknown.

Currently I am counting the assets for each status. An example of a status is: "available".

The problem is that:

- either assets get counted more than once, if they have had alternating values for status in the past (which they pretty much all do)
- or, I receive an error because I am searching for the most recent log entry for each asset but some assets have no log entries and the aggregate function in DQL fails

I am trying the following code:

```
 $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
 $qb->select('COUNT(a)')
  ->from('AppAssetBundle:Asset', 'a')
  ->leftJoin('a.logEntries', 'l')
  ->where('l.status = '.$status_id)
  ->andWhere('l.id = MAX(l.id)')
 ;
 return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

The error is:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function

Replacing `->andWhere()` by `->having()` did not work either.

Does anyone know how to obtain the most recent entity of an association, **if any**?

If there are no associated fields, I would like my entire query to return 0 instead of an error :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, couldn't you simply add a createdAt field in the assocation entity like so:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class YourClass
{
    protected $asset_id;

    protected $log_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function prePersist()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime('now');
    }
}
```

Then you could simply sort by date and grab the latest entry.

Comment: There is a createdAt field, but whether I grab the highest id or the most recent date doesn't make a difference to the problem. The problem is: how do I grab the latest entry in the query? And if that latest entry is not of the status I am looking for, or it is non-existent as there are no associated entries, the COUNT() should return 0.